# Wicket and Netbeans - some files are not openning

Tags: java, netbeans, wicket

I have a Wicket page that simply not opens on Netbeans anymore, sometimes the HTML file and sometimes the .java file of the page, but never both opens together. I have to open the files on other editor.

The weird is that the page is rendered and works fine. Any idea why?

It gives me a strange log, that don't helps to track the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.wicket.tree.ComponentIdFinder.visitNewClass(ComponentIdFinder.java:67)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.wicket.tree.ComponentIdFinder.visitNewClass(ComponentIdFinder.java:34)
... log continues
```

I found this list of issues on Netbeans report with other devs with the same problem: [Netbeans issues list](http://statistics.netbeans.org/exceptions/detail.do?id=145470).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging manually the files I realized that the problem was in a DropDownChoice filled dynamically:

```
DropDownChoice addressesChoice = new DropDownChoice<>(
    "address",
    new PropertyModel(getModel(), "address"),
    new ArrayList<Address>(),
    new ChoiceRenderer<>("zipCode")
);
```

Adresses choices were filled dynamically based on selection of other DropDownChoice. The problem was with the choices of addresses, that is with no reference. So I splitted it on declaration-instantiation steps:

```
ArrayList<Addresses> addressesList = new ArrayList<Addresses>();
...
DropDownChoice addressesChoice = new DropDownChoice<>(
    "address",
    new PropertyModel(getModel(), "address"),
    addressesList,
    new ChoiceRenderer<>("zipCode")
);
```

That fixed the problem.